# Extract value from json nested key in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
    {
"problems": [{
    "Diabetes":[{
        "medications":[{
            "medicationsClasses":[{
                "className":[{
                    "associatedDrug":[{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }],
                    "associatedDrug#2":[{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }]
                }],
                "className2":[{
                    "associatedDrug":[{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }],
                    "associatedDrug#2":[{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "labs":[{
            "missing_field": "missing_value"
        }]
    }],
    "Asthma":[{}]
}]}
```

I tried to fetch "aspirin" name value. meddetails is a column name. Postgresql db.

Select meddetails ->'problems' ->> 'Diabetes'->>'medications' ->>'className' ->>'associatedDrug'->>'name' from details;

Comment: "I tried to fetch "aspirin" name value."  What happened?

Comment: Select meddetails ->'problems' ->> 'Diabetes'->>'medications' ->>'className' ->>'associatedDrug'->>'name' from details; didnot work

Comment: How do you mean it "didnot work"? What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Comment: I got error. SQL Error[42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist:text ->> unknown

Comment: Why do you put everything into an array although each array only contains a single element. That makes queries way more complicated then they need to be. And why isn't that column defined as `jsonb`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried several different ways of querying and none would work beyond 'problems'. Then I realised you have unnecessary `[...]` in your json. You should remove them, then it works.

```
drop table if exists t;
create temp table t (meddetails json);


insert into t (meddetails)
values ('    {
"problems": {
    "Diabetes":{
        "medications":{
            "medicationsClasses":{
                "className":{
                    "associatedDrug":{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    },
                    "associatedDrug#2":{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }
                },
                "className2":{
                    "associatedDrug":{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    },
                    "associatedDrug#2":{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "labs":{
            "missing_field": "missing_value"
        }
    },
    "Asthma":{}
}}');

SELECT meddetails->'problems'->'Diabetes'->'medications'->'medicationsClasses'->'className'->'associatedDrug'->>'name'
FROM t;
```

FYI `->` returns a json level which can be queried further. `->>` returns the text of the element, so I believe you will only want that at the end of the chain.

Comment: SELECT meddetails->'problems'->'Diabetes'->'medications'->'medicationsClasses'->'className'->'associatedDrug'->>'name'
This query giving empty column

Comment: Have you removed the square brackets from your data?